# Antlr4ts not working with Angular Version 13

Tags: angular, antlr

I am trying to use antlr4ts with angular version 13 when I am trying to parse any string I am getting error.
The below is my service code where I am trying to parse a string

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ANTLRInputStream, CommonToken, CommonTokenStream } from 'antlr4ts';
import { MYLexer } from 'src/assets/lexpar/MyLexer';
import {
  DatuMapParser,
  ProgramContext,
} from 'src/assets/lexpar/MyParser';

declare var process: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TransformationService {
  inputStream: ANTLRInputStream;
  lexer: DatuMapLexer;
  parser: DatuMapParser;
  tokenStream: CommonTokenStream;
  ruleTree: ProgramContext;

  constructor() {}

  parseRule(ruleText: string): any {
    this.inputStream = new ANTLRInputStream(ruleText);
    this.lexer = new MyLexer(this.inputStream);
    this.tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(this.lexer);
    this.parser = new MyParser(this.tokenStream);
    this.ruleTree = this.parser.program();
    return this.ruleTree;
  }
}
```

I am getting below error in browser console

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: process is not defined ReferenceError: process is not defined at 74 (util.js:109:1) at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1) at 6094 (assertion_error.js:35:16) at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1) at 431 (assert.js:36:22) at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1) at 8043 (ANTLRInputStream.js:15:16) at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1) at 3039 (index.js:20:14) at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1) at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:1) at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165:1) at zone.js:1278:1 at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1) at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25444:1) at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:1) at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:1) at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:585:1)
```

could anyone please help me with fixing this issue

Comment: You might want to try using the official TypeScript runtime for Antlr version 4.12.0 that was just released in the last week or so. It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is a typical one when you try to use a library that contains access to Node.js modules in a browser. Since you cannot use Node.js there, you obviously cannot use any API that makes use of Node.js functionality. The other parts of the library, however, are usable also in a Browser. Unfortunately, there's still the import of the Node.js packages in the code and you have to take care to provide them somehow.

The usually approach with bundlers like Webpack or rollup.js is to shim those (using polyfills). IIRC Webpack does this automatically, so I wonder why you see the error. In rollup.js you have to explicitly import polyfills (e.g. `npm --save-dev i rollup-plugin-polyfill-node`) and configure the packer with them.

They will then insert the shims in the place of the imports and the error should go away.